# How do I display PHP array in Google Chart

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, google-visualization

I'd like to diplay my array in google stacked column chart. I generated the array looks like this.

```
array(n) { ["5pm"]=> int(4) ["6pm"]=> int(0),... } //Monday
array(n) { ["5pm"]=> int(5) ["6pm"]=> int(1),... } //Tuesday
...
array(n) { ["5pm"]=> int(4) ["6pm"]=> int(2),... } //Sunday
```

The number of entries in array needs to vary (depends on entries in database, but is the same for all days).

The JS from google charts needs to look like this

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([    
    ['Hours', '5pm', '6pm',...],
    ['Mon', 4, 0],
    ['Tue', 5, 1],
       ...
    ['Sun', 4, 2]
]);
```

Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: What's the problem you are facing? Also, what do u mean by ```number of entries in array needs to vary(but is the same for all days)``` ?

Comment: @mi6crazyheart - I think it means that all the days will have the same time period (5pm - 10pm, for example) but that time period can change depending on what is in the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heer is a sample code where I'm getting data from PHP & passing that to JavaScript for plotting the chart. One thing needs to check that all rows should have an equal number of elements.

So, according to your question, all "Time Periods" rows should have an equal number of elements else, it'll not work.

```
<?php
$chartData = array(
        array('Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'),
        array('2014', 1000, 400, 200),
        array('2015', 1170, 460, 250),
        array('2016', 660, 1120, 300),
        array('2017', 1030, 540, 350)
    );
$chartDataInJson = json_encode($chartData);
?>

<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php echo $chartDataInJson; ?>);

        var options = {
          chart: {
            title: 'Company Performance',
            subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
          }
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));

        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="columnchart_material" style="width: 800px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope it'll clear all of your doubt.

Comment: It was not exactly a doubt, but thanks...It helped me a lot to see how to do this right...Works fantastic

Comment: It works like a charm. Great solution, thanks Suresh !